# Sending message to custom group using SignalR

Tags: c#, signalr

I have a Hub Server sending messages to my clients.

My clients can belong to a Group (that I have defined) and that group can invariable change.

I store this Group list in a dictionary class.

At the moment I send messages to each clients seperately so:

```
var myListA = 'get all clients from a collection that belongs to Group A'
```

I then do:

```
foreach (string hubUserId in myListA )
{
    context.Clients.Client(hubUserId).broadcastMessage('some data');
}
```

Ideally, i would like to do this:

```
var myListA = 'get all clients from a collection that belongs to Group A'
context.Clients.Group(myListA).broadcastMessage('some data');
```

However, this requires I use/create a Hub Group. My Group is external and is indigenous to other parts of my code/application.

Is there a way to do this at all?

Thanks

Comment: Well clearly you can't use `Clients.Group()` if you haven't got any actual SignalR groups set up, so you probably have to stick with what you have got. All you may be able to do is wrap up what you have in an extension method to make your application code cleaner

Comment: @Rhumborl Hi, thanks for your comment/time.  that was what I had assumed as well.  Was just hoping greater minds than mine could see a way to do this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SignalR groups work using a publish-subscribe model You will have to synchronize your application groups to the hub groups. When a client connects, load its group name from your dictionary / database and assign it to the hub group. When its group membership changes, update the hub groups accordingly.

Find more information to this [over here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections).

Comment: Hi, yes that was what I was looking at too. the problem I got is that when the hub client connects the 1st time it will not belong to any Group.  The Group designation is decided by the User and can be done at any time and can and wil change all the time.  I created a dictionary class to handle this logic. I would have to then remove the Client from any previous Group and assign to the new Group.  but, I would have to handle this outside the 'normal' Hub class and I would need to somehow check if the User/Clients already exists in a previous Group. All very messy for me to handle...